# How to pass data to a file from stdin in the shell

Tags: c, shell, stdin

My task is to write a C program to illustrate the mv command using system Calls:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 8192
int main(){
int input_fd,output_fd;
ssize_t ret_in, ret_out; //number of bytes returned by read(), write()
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
output_fd=open("sss", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
if(output_fd==-1){
        perror("open");
        return 3;
}
while((ret_in=read(stdin, buffer, BUF_SIZE))>0){
        ret_out=write (output_fd, buffer,(ssize_t) ret_in);
        if(ret_out!=ret_in){
                perror("write");
                return 4;
        }
}
close(output_fd);
input_fd=open("sss", O_RDONLY);
while((ret_in=read(input_fd,buffer, BUF_SIZE))>0)
        ret_out=write(stdout, buffer,(ssize_t) ret_in);
close(input_fd);
return 0;
}
```

How to run that code in the shell and pass it text from stdin?
Please, give me exapmle of passing data to a file from stdin in the shell

Comment: The code has issues that would cause unexpected behaviour. Is it the complete source?

Comment: yes, but I took it from the book and there can be errors intentionally

Comment: Openning a file for writing `O_CREAT` included does not always work, if you don't have permissions for example it will fail, `open()` would return `-1` and then you can check `errno` to verify why. The code does not do that. Also, what exactly are you expecting. The question does not explain what is the expected behaviour.

Comment: See [ask]. If you copied from a book, where is your own contribution to the code and what is your **specific** problem? Also this seems to be a bad book, as it uses a deprecated signature for `main`. And `mv` does not copy a file within the same filesystem.

Comment: My specific problem is that I do not know how to run this code with data passed from stdin in it. My own contribution is that I've tried several ways of running it but if u mean the contribution in the code it doesn't matter concerning my specific problem.

Comment: Therein lies the problem. We are happy to help, but the answer to how to run the code is very clear in the code you've posted. If you are asking that question, then it tells all that you do not understand what the code does, making it highly unlikely that it is your work-product. Please take time to look into what each line of code is doing. Read the man page for each call. Then if you are still stuck. Ask the specific question you are stuck on which will be much narrower than "How do I run this code.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix your code and change `stdout` to 1 (or `STDOUT_FILENO`) and `stdin` to 0 (or `STDIN_FILENO`). The others are `FILE *` and belong to fread and fwrite. Any decent compiler should have warned you there...

`./MoveCommand < filename` is one way.

This will redirect the contents of `filename` to `stdin` and it will be written to the file "sss", after which this file is read and the contents echoed to `stdout`.

So you're doing `cat filename` essentially, with an extra copy to some fixed file.

`./Movecommand` by itself is also possible. But then you have to type input yourself (this is `stdin` at that point) and when you want to signal you're done rnter Ctrl+D (Linux or Mac) or Ctrl+Z (Windows). Then it will echo everything you typed back to you, and the contents are also in "sss".

You can also use it in a pipe, of course, so `ls -l | ./Movecommand` e.g. Try it.

Comment: I've tried ./MoveCommand text.txt. The result is that file sss is created but the size of it is zero. However, the content of text.txt is not empty. Also I've tried ./Movecommand by itself but then when I end typing and tap enter it's said that such command doesn't exist.

Comment: @Stranger You need  < ,"less than", text.txt, say, to read from text.txt

Comment: @Stranger ./Movecommand by itself should just hang, right? Enter text (enter does nothing special) and end with Ctrl+D.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, sorry I mean I used ./MoveCommand <text.txt. And yes u r right: it should hang but doesn't

Comment: @Stranger found another mistake : change stdin --> 0 and stdout --> 1

Comment: you are genius. Thanks very much, post it like an answer I'll tick it

Comment: @Stranger It's in my answer now.